# Spring integration - Difference between AmqpOutboundEndpoint and RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

i am trying to write my first AMQP publisher via spring integration using an instance of AmqpOutboundEndpoint.

1. I don't understand what is the difference between RabbitTemplate and AmqpOutboundEndPoint since AmqpOutboundEndpoint is using an instance of RabbitTemplate.
2. I would like to use an AMQP gateway to separate 2 different components of my application (Business component and Integration component)
   Is it valid to use an AqmpOutboundEndPoint to publish a message when i need to switch the routing key according to the published message type? All examples i found in internet are using a hardcoded routing key for the AMQP gateway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, welcome to the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/)

So, first of all you are right,  `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` is really fully based on the `RabbitTemplate` because it is a good implementation for sending messages over AMQP.

On the other hand the endpoint is a Channel Adapter to receive messages via internal Integration channel.

So, you have to decide for yourself if you really need the whole Integration solution or just sending to the AMQP from your own code is enough.

That endpoint allows you to determine routingKey at runtime against requestMessage using SpEL.

See documentation on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack

Comment: Is there an advantage to build a gateway and note the RabbitTemplate directly ? more flexibility or something else ? As you say, the producer and the consumer are my system, this is an internal integration.

Comment: If you don't build Spring Integration application, I don't see reason to break your mind with extra code. Direct `RabbitTemplate` usage and over the gateway are really for different task and solutions. If you don't feel that you need Spring Integration in your project, don't waste your time to understand the difference and advantages